# Listen for notification from another node.js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have 2 loopback node.js application. In 1 app i created a socket.io server and emitting some events as follows..

```
app.io = require('socket.io')(app.start());

    app.io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
      var watcher = chokidar.watch('transactions.xlsx', {ignored: /^\./, persistent: true});
       watcher
        .on('change', function(path) {
          xlsx({
            input: "transactions.xlsx",
            output: null
          }, function(err, transactions) {
            if(err) {
              console.error(err);
            } else {
              console.log(transactions);
              app.io.sockets.volatile.emit('notification', transactions);
            }
          });
        });
    });
```

How can i listen for this notification event in app2.

My Flow should be:

`Emit from app1----->listen in app2----->then send notification to client side`.

Please share your ideas.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one node app to be socket client of another node app (which is socket server) you should use https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client

Answer (score 0):

> 1. create connection for other running node.js app
> 2. pass the notification as emit with other connection
>
> `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
>       <script src="http://localhost:3200/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
>       <script>
>       // creating a new websocket
>       var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3200');
>       var other_socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3400'); // url of other node.js app
>       // on every message recived we print the new datas inside the #container div
>       socket.on('notification', function (data) {
>           // convert the json string into a valid javascript object
>           $('#container').html(data[0].Balance);
>           $('time').html('Last Update:' + new Date());
>           other_socket.emit('notification', data);
>       });
>       </script>`
>
> For Emit from app1----->listen in app2 directly; use socket.io-client library as follow -

```
`var io = require('socket.io-client');
 var client1 = io.connect('socketURL1');
 var client2 = io.connect('socketURL2');
 client1.on('notification', function (data) {
 client2.emit('notification', JSON.stringify(data));
 });`
```

Comment: thanks..But actually what i need is my node.js app should act as socket client which is listening for event from another node.js app

Comment: please, use the code below in your app to listen from another node.js app (update the socket urls)